# Change control in property window for custom activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-rehosting

I have a custom activity that has a couple of arguments and a couple of properties. When dropping the activity in to the rehosted designer, both arguments and properties are visible from the properties window where the user can enter values or variable names etc..

For one of the properties (in the properties window), I don't want the user to be able to type in it, but instead replace the text box with a combo box, so they can select from a list of values. This, I can't seem to find an answer for.

I have used some code from an existing entry that was marked as solved, but my request is a slightly different requirement.

In my custom activity, I have placed the following above the property in question:

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(ComboBoxTest), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
```

And have created the ComboBoxTest class, inheriting from UITypeEditor:

```
public class ComboBoxTest : UITypeEditor
    {
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
        }
        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            var editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
            ListBox list = new ListBox();
            //ComboBox list = new ComboBox();

            // Your code here to populate the list box with your items
            list.Items.Add("A");
            list.Items.Add("B");
            list.Items.Add("C");

            EventHandler onclick = (sender, e) =>
            {
                editorService.CloseDropDown();
            };

            list.Click += onclick;

            editorService.DropDownControl(list);

            list.Click -= onclick;

            return (list.SelectedItem != null) ? list.SelectedItem : null;
        }
    }
```

However, when dropping the activity in to the designer, the property still has the text box in the property window, and no combo box appears. I can't even seem to debug it as it doesn't hit any breakpoints.

Would anyone happen to know if A) I'm doing it the right way or B) If I have an error somewhere or even C) Has a much better approach that I should be using.

I hope all that makes sense. Thank you for reading!

Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Debug.Print("write something")` and look into the Output window to debug Designer stuff.

Also try

```
[Editor(typeof(ComboBoxTest), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
```

instead